# Download / Export the content of one or more tables

Tags: javascript, excel, vbscript, qlikview, vba

I am really new to the `QlikView` products.

I have two tables. The second is only visible when it has records (under certain conditions).

I would like to use the `XL` button from the first table and append the contents of the second table if it is visible.

I note that I have to deploy this on the QlikView server.

Here is the button that I refer to:
[image]

I was thinking to create a trigger and somehow catch the `XL` button's click event in order to override its functionality.

But since I am new newbie in this technology and in VBScript (macros) as well I thought of asking this question here.

Any pointers would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have the XL button on the second table you can export data to XL  by right clicking and press "Send to Excel". You can also add the XL button to the table by going into [Properties] - [Caption] and ticking "Send to excel".

Past that you would manually have to copy and append it yourself.

But if I were you, I would create a third table that contains both tables and add the conditional statement from the second table that only output the results you want.

The second table must have a logic/condition set to only show the results you want, there are different ways of doing it so try to find out where and how that logic is working.

As a tip, you do not have to think about macros as a first solution to a problem.

Comment: Do you have a sample of the approach that you suggest ? It is not obvious to me how to solve this.